# how to concat all column data of a grouped row?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Given the following table:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|       Account      |  Company  |
+--------------------+-----------+
| gloria.harding     | FB        |
| gloria.harding     | Twitter   |
| bryant.schuman     | Google    |
| jerry.maxwell      | Apple     |
| rachel.heptinstall | FB        |
| rachel.heptinstall | Twitter   |
| rachel.heptinstall | Instagram |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

I want to group the result by **Account** but I need the **Company** column of each row in the group to be concatenated and display all of them in an anonymous column like so:

```
+--------------------+------------------------+
|       Account      |      'Companies'       |
+--------------------+------------------------+
| gloria.harding     | FB, Twitter            |
| bryant.schuman     | Google                 |
| jerry.maxwell      | Apple                  |
| rachel.heptinstall | FB, Twitter, Instagram |
+--------------------+------------------------+
```

Is this possible to achieve on TSQL?

The first requirement can easily be achieved by grouping the **Account** column but I don't know how to achieve the latter.

Comment: which dbms you currenly using?

Comment: @T.Peter SQL Server 2016

Comment: I'm glad I ask cause I think `string_agg()` does not support SQL server 2016...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following - using `stuff()`

```
select distinct Account,
STUFF((Select ','+Company
from tablename T1
where T1.account=T2.account
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') from tablename T2
```

Comment: ahhh the old way using `FOR XML` , I'm so glad we got `string_agg` nowadays...

Comment: I was fixated on using GROUP cause grouping the row is all over my head. I forgot about distinct lmao. But this is the first time I see function STUFF. Thanks!

Comment: @T.Peter, yes old way but string_agg not available before 2017!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution than working with XML for someone who is using SQL Server 2017 and above. Microsoft introduced `STRING_AGG` command and this fits perfectly into what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Account, (SELECT STRING_AGG(Company, ',')
                          FROM TableName T1
                          WHERE T1.Account = T2.Account) 
FROM TableName T2;
```